# Managing lots of controls in FlowLayoutPanel

Tags: winforms, user-interface, c#-4.0, design-time

I have a C# 4.0 Winform app, the main form of which is visually divided in half: a TreeView on the left (for navigation of data) and a FlowLayoutPanel on the right.  The contents of the FlowLayoutPanel changes based on user interaction (mainly with the TreeView).

The content to be shown in the FlowLayoutPanel is comparmentalized into a number of "blocks" - some are UserControls whilst others (I'm embarrassed to say) are Panels containing various Controls.

**My issue** is that the number of "blocks" is now too many to see in the Visual Studio form designer, and I can't make the form large enough to see them all; this makes it hard to verify how the UI will look without running it.

**How can** I manage the contents of the FlowLayoutPanel so that I can see all of the controls, or am I going about it wrong?

Comment: Sounds very busy; would it be possible to break it down into multiple forms - perhaps a Wizard-type experience?

Comment: Potentially, but I think the user experience would suffer (lots of windows to manage), so I'd rather stick with the current high-level direction if possible.

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is.  With AutoScroll = true, you should be able to just scroll while in the designer.

Comment: HurrDurr - that's it @LarsTech, pls add as an answer and I'll award it to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While in the designer, make sure you have AutoScroll property set to true, which will enable you to scroll the FlowLayoutPanel child controls while in the designer view.